# Spark SQL: Error when using aliased column in SELECT clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `ORDERS` and `SELLERS` tables with the following schema:

```
scala> spark.sql("desc ORDERS").show()
+---------------+---------+-------+
|       col_name|data_type|comment|
+---------------+---------+-------+
|       order_id|   string|   null|
|     product_id|   string|   null|
|      seller_id|   string|   null|
|           date|   string|   null|
|num_pieces_sold|   string|   null|
|  bill_raw_text|   string|   null|
+---------------+---------+-------+


scala> spark.sql("desc SELLERS").show()
+------------+---------+-------+
|    col_name|data_type|comment|
+------------+---------+-------+
|   seller_id|   string|   null|
| seller_name|   string|   null|
|daily_target|   string|   null|
+------------+---------+-------+
```

I am getting an error with the following query. I understand we can use subquery (or `withColumn`) to avoid this but wondering if there is an alternate way.

```
scala> 
q3: String =
"
 SELECT
    o.seller_id,
    o.num_pieces_sold/s.daily_target AS ratio,
    avg(ratio) AS percent_contribution
 FROM orders o
 JOIN sellers s ON o.seller_id = s.seller_id
 GROUP BY o.seller_id
 "

scala> spark.sql(q3).show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`ratio`' given input columns: [o.bill_raw_text, s.seller_id, o.date, o.seller_id, o.order_id, o.product_id, s.seller_name, o.num_pieces_sold, s.daily_target]; line 5 pos 6;
'Aggregate [seller_id#8], [seller_id#8, (cast(num_pieces_sold#10 as double) / cast(daily_target#20 as double)) AS ratio#421, 'avg('ratio) AS percent_contribution#422]
+- Join Inner, (seller_id#8 = seller_id#18)
   :- SubqueryAlias `o`
   :  +- SubqueryAlias `orders`
   :     +- Relation[order_id#6,product_id#7,seller_id#8,date#9,num_pieces_sold#10,bill_raw_text#11] parquet
   +- SubqueryAlias `s`
      +- SubqueryAlias `sellers`
         +- Relation[seller_id#18,seller_name#19,daily_target#20] parquet
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is indirectly linked to the error... the expression `o.num_pieces_sold/s.daily_target` is neither aggregated nor part of your `group by` columns

Comment: in addition to what @ernest_k mentioned, `ratio` can't be used in the same query..you should be referring to the ratio calculation/use a sub-query.

Comment: @ernest_k It doesn't work even if I rewrite it to use "first_value" function. I removed the functions for brevity.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala in this case aliasing and reffering in another column is not working. with out alias and using directly with another column with `avg` functtion in this case its working fine see my answer with fullexample. seems like parser is reading sql like thatt from the spark api framework it self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like catalyst is not recognizing (by design) the intermediate expression `ratio` and again it was used in another column like normal sql

direct usage with `avg` function is working like below with out aliasing the ratio

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

object Ratio extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName(getClass.getName).enableHiveSupport()
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate

  import spark._
  import spark.implicits._


  sql(
    """
      |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders
      |(
      |  order_id string
      |, product_id String
      |, seller_id String
      |, date int
      |, num_pieces_sold String
      |, bill_raw_text String
      |)
    """.stripMargin)


  sql(
    """
      |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sellers
      |(
      |  seller_id string
      |, seller_name String
      |, daily_target String )
    """.stripMargin)

  sql("SHOW tables ").show

  val df1 = Seq(
    ("1", "1", "1", 20200520, 10, "rawtext"),
    ("2", "2", "2", 20200521, 11, "rawtext1")
  ).toDF("order_id", "product_id", "seller_id", "date", "num_pieces_sold", "bill_raw_text")

  df1.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("orders")
  df1.show

  val df2 = Seq(
    ("1", "seller_name1", "11"),
    ("2", "seller_name2", "22")
  ).toDF("seller_id", "seller_name", "daily_target")

  df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("sellers")
  df2.show


  val q3 =
    """
      | SELECT
      |    o.seller_id,
      |    avg(o.num_pieces_sold/ s.daily_target) AS percent_contribution
      | FROM orders o
      | JOIN sellers s ON o.seller_id = s.seller_id
      |  GROUP BY o.seller_id
    """.stripMargin

  spark.sql(q3).show


}
```

Result :

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|database|    tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+-------------+-----------+
 default|       orders|      false|
| default|      sellers|      false|
+--------+-------------+-----------+

20/05/18 21:08:29 INFO log: Updating table stats fast for orders
20/05/18 21:08:29 INFO log: Updated size of table orders to 2949
+--------+----------+---------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|order_id|product_id|seller_id|    date|num_pieces_sold|bill_raw_text|
+--------+----------+---------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|       1|         1|        1|20200520|             10|      rawtext|
|       2|         2|        2|20200521|             11|     rawtext1|
+--------+----------+---------+--------+---------------+-------------+


+---------+------------+------------+
|seller_id| seller_name|daily_target|
+---------+------------+------------+
|        1|seller_name1|          11|
|        2|seller_name2|          22|
+---------+------------+------------+

+---------+--------------------+
|seller_id|percent_contribution|
+---------+--------------------+
|        1|  0.9090909090909091|
|        2|                 0.5|
+---------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Ram, appreciate the answer but I already have this working, by using the entire expression within avg function, before I posted the question. I was curious about why aliasing didn't work.

Comment: It's by design is what observed